# AWS ElasticBeanstalk and AWS CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch

Can someone explain me, how I can log and monitoring HTTP calls which are requested to ElasticBeanstalk instances with CloudWatch?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is described in [Using Elastic Beanstalk with Amazon CloudWatch Logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.cloudwatchlogs.html):

> With CloudWatch Logs, you can monitor and archive your Elastic
>   Beanstalk application, system, and custom log files. Furthermore, you
>   can configure alarms that make it easier for you to take actions in
>   response to specific log stream events that your metric filters
>   extract. The CloudWatch Logs agent installed on each Amazon EC2 in
>   your environment publishes metric data points to the CloudWatch
>   service for each log group you configure. [...]